# How to get geoclue to use GPS data or hard code the location on 22.04

Tags: gps, location

Using either the Google or Mozilla location services or the ISP geolocation service gives crap results.

There is an attached USB U-Blox 7 GPS that is used as a NTP source with gpsd and the documentation for modem manager implies that it can interface with a GPS, but it, modem manager, doesn't see any devices.

NTP has been running fine with gpsd for years, so obviously gpsd is working.

The question is, does anyone know how to either force geoclue to use the USB GPS or how to hard code geoclue for my location?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491645/edit) to clarify: Are you saying that gpsd cannot detect your GPS device nor use the device output? Or are you saying that GeoClue is not using gpsd output? Or are you saying that you're not sure how all these systems work together and asking how to troubleshoot the problem? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: Including the results of lsusb in your question can help because this will show the exact chip make and model for your GPS device.